# program with boost thread 1.51 doesn't build

Tags: c++, gcc, boost-thread

I am trying to compile a program using boost thread with the latest version. I am using

gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)

With the 1.50 I had an issue saying that the reference to `boost::thread::~thrad()` couldn't be found. So I updated to the new one I got the following

```
      /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:65: error: expected ';' before 'thread_data'
      /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:68: error: expected `;' before 'thread_data'
      /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:88: error: expected ';' before 'thread_data'
      /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:91: error: expected `;' before 'void'
      /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:105: error: expected ';' before 'thread_data'
      /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:108: error: expected `;' before 'void'
      /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:121: error: expected ';' before 'private'
      /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:153: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
      /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:153: error: there are no arguments to 'BOOST_THREAD_RV_REF' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'BOOST_THREAD_RV_REF' must be available
      /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:153: error: (if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
      /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:153: error: expected `)' before 'f'
      /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:153: error: invalid in-class initialization of static data member of non-integral type 'boost::detail::thread_data_ptr'
      /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:153: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
```

I had no clue why is doing this way. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Are you sure it was an undefined reference to `boost::thread::~thrad()`, not `boost::thread::~thread()`? Also, could you give a [minimal example](http://sscce.org) which has this problem.

Comment: This looks a bit to me like you try to compile with an unconfigured boost source treee...

Comment: Did you link with the `boost_thread` library (i.e. put `-lboost_thread` on gcc's command line)?

Comment: yes I am linking against the library.It used to build correctly until 1.49.0

Comment: @PlasmaHH: how to chekc that situation of "unconfigured boost source tree"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue with g++ 4.2.1 on OSX, though I don't think its a compiler issue per se.

I had previously installed boost libraries and headers installed to `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include` by invoking b2 install.  This works on a new installation, but it doesn't correctly overwrite a previous boost installation (I had 1.49).  All I had to do was point my build at the boost build directory I was using, or to delete `/usr/local/include/boost` and run b2 install again.  The first time I ran b2 install it only copied the libs which was fast, the second time it took much longer and copied over all the header files.

Comment: Hi ( coming back with a delay to thank ). After struggling a bit there was something in my local installation messing up ( including some unexpected linked file ). At the end I decided to reinstall boost from scratch and everything worked out. Thanks for the tips.